# why $\pi_1(S^2)=0?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres

why $\pi_1(S^2)=0$  ?

I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116083/proof-of-pi-1sn-0-if-n-geq-2) but I didn't understand the answer.

**My thinking** :If  $n=2$  then $\pi_1(S^2)\neq 0$ because $S^2$ is not contractible.

Now if I take $S^2-\{x\}$  then $\pi_1\left(S^2-\{x\}\right)=0$ because  $S^2-\{x\}$ is contractible

Here $S^2-\{x\} \neq S^2$ .I am not getting why $\pi_1(S^2)=0?$

Comment: $S^2$ don’t need to be contractible. Any loop on $S^2$ should be.

Comment: you just have to know that every loop is homotopic to one that misses a point. then you can remove that point.

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not cantractible, but it is simply connected

Comment: ok@Timkinsella you mean loop  in$ S^2$  is homotopic to loop in $S^2-\{x\}$. Am i right ?

Comment: You have to use Van Kampen theorem to conclude the result. The idea of the proof is that $S^2$ can be written as the union of two simply connected spaces whose intersection is path-connected.

Comment: Why didn't you ask for clarification there via a comment?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese actually,on the given link post  all answers are  different.I was confused

Comment: @jasmine yes, although that might be harder than just using van kampen

Comment: although, what's nice about the "misses a point" thing is it generalizes to show $\pi_n(S^m)=0$  for n<m.

Comment: It may be easier to *apply* Van Kampen's theorem than to apply the method suggested by @Timkinsella. Nonetheless, that exact method is a part of the *proof* of Van Kampen's theorem, so it's very highly worthwhile for your long term understanding to understand that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \geq 2$. The $n$-sphere $S^n$ is simply connected.
Write the sphere as union of the two subsets obtained by removing the north pole and south pole, respectively. Using spherical coordinates we can write

\begin{align*}
O_1 := S^n \setminus \lbrace (0, \ldots, 0, 1 \rbrace = \Phi([0,2\pi]^{n-1} \times (0, \pi]) \\
O_2 := S^n \setminus \lbrace (0, \ldots, 0, -1 \rbrace = \Phi([0,2\pi]^{n-1} \times [0, \pi)).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
O_1 \cap O_2 = S^n \setminus \lbrace (0, \ldots, 0, 1), (0, \ldots, 0,-1) \rbrace = \Phi([0,2\pi]^{n-1} \times (0,\pi)).
\end{equation*}
We see that $O_1,O_2$ and $O_1 \cap O_2$ are pathwise connected.
By means of the stereographic projection (taking as projection center the north- or south pole), $O_1$ and $O_2$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $\pi_1(O_1) = \pi_1(O_2) = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$.

Now for a open cover $\lbrace O_i : i \in I \rbrace$ of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ with
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{i \in I}U_i \neq \emptyset
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\forall i,j \in I, U_i \cap U_j \mbox{ is pathwise connected}
\end{equation}
and $\iota_i : U_i \to X$ the set-theoretic inclusion map then $X$ is
pathwise connected and the group $\pi_1(X)$ is generated by
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{i \in I}{\pi_1(\iota_i)(\pi_1(U_i))}.
\end{equation}

From this result we conclude $\pi_1(S^n) = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$.